# Position sticky in Figma

Tags: website-design, interface-design, figma

Is it possible to apply fixed positioning depending on the point where the `scrollY` is (on the vertical axis)? Just like you would with CSS with position sticky?

Comment: I'm thinking this video should tell you how to do it: [Figma Tutorial: Device Frames and Scrolling - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ST6DOO11zuA). There's also [this](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051747774-Preserve-scroll-position-in-prototypes) and [that](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039818734-Prototype-scrolling-with-overflow-behavior#Create_fixed_objects_in_a_prototype).

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to create a [fixed element on scroll](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039818734-Prototype-scrolling-with-overflow-behavior#Create_fixed_objects_in_a_prototype), there is no equivalent of CSS position sticky (fixed starting from specific Y) in Figma. You would need to either use other tools for that such as ProtoPie or simply explain this behavior to developers in another way (e.g. add some notes to the file with the expected start position of sticky objects).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer in this video explain by Figma experts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWdlAL4Ql90

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but can you please explain what the basic steps are.  We are looking for long answers here, not link only answers, because links have a tendency to rot over time. Thanks.